# Nested form sealization is not working in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am developing a web application. I have a page with a form, `form1`, and I am pushing another page which also has a form, `form2`, inside `form1`. Both the forms have some values. I want to serialize both the forms. When I specify the root form (`form1`) like `$('#form1').serialize();` it serializes the root form (`form1`) only, not `form2`.

If specify like this `$('#form1, #form2').serialize();` and `$('form').serialize();` it sealizes all the forms.

What is wrong with this jQuery `$('form1').serialize();` which serializes root form only, not form2?

I tried with a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kaleeswaran/3ZLhu/), in which it works fine. What could be the issue in my web application form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even it is not supported for your purpose you can use `:input` selector.

```
$('#form1 :input').serialize();
```

for the performance using filter highly recomended.

```
$('#form1 > *').filter(':input').serialize();
```

If you can explain why you are using nested forms maybe we can suggest some workaround. for example if you only use the second form for AJAX request you can cover it by a div to easily select or give those form items an extra class and use the similar selector for them.

Comment: i have generated reusable page(form2). I need this page in many tabs of my application so i generated as subpage with form(form2). and when i push this page(form2) in another page(form1 page) which is also having the form elemet(form1).

Comment: if it is the case generate the form2Page just with form elements (not in a form tag) and cover it with a div to select easily with jQ and just implement insert this form where ever you want. if you only need form2 elements insert it in to form element. This is kind of good approach (I think).

Answer (score 2):

Nested forms are not allowed in HTML. jQuery isn't designed to handle them. Don't create them.

Comment: To add to this, the reason it work in jsFiddle is because it has removed the invalid nested form from the HTML. Check it in Firebug and you'll see.

Comment: -1 because it is not a solution or suggestion. just saying "doesn t support that" or  "don t do that" is not an answer. Unfortunately in some cases we have to develop this kind of unsupported/unsuggested stuff.